# Array of tuples as argument - types look the same but aren't

Tags: swift, types, swift2

As part of trying to create an ordered dictionary inspired lonely by [this blog post](http://timekl.com/blog/2014/06/02/learning-swift-ordered-dictionaries/), I'm trying to implement a map function. My ordered dictionary is essentially a wrapper struct for an array of tuples. Here's the relevant part of my struct:

```
struct od<kT: Hashable, vT> {
    typealias kv = (key:kT, value:vT)
    private var tuples: Array<kv> = []
    init() {}
    init(_ tupleArgs: kv...) {
        tuples = tupleArgs
    }
    func map<nkT:Hashable, nvT>(transform: (kv) -> (key:nkT, value:nvT)) -> od<nkT, nvT> {
        let arr = tuples.map(transform)
        return od<nkT, nvT>(arr)
    }
}
```

The problem occurs when trying to initialise the return value at `od<nkT, nvT>(are)` and the error I get is:

```
Cannot convert value of type '[(key: kT, value: vT)]' to expected argument type '[(key: _, value: _)]'
```

I initially one-lined the body of the map function, the error message was a bit more cryptic but essentially the same. (Xcode complains about the type of the transform function rather than the type of the return value)

In case it is at all helpful, I also have [a gist with the full code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b0668bc7220e4ffc43f0).

Comment: I found it rather difficult to phrase where the problem lies, so the title of this question might be terrible, if anyone knows of a way to improve it, I'm entirely open to it.

Comment: You have only defined an init method that takes a variable argument list, but in `od<nkT, nvT>(arr)` you are passing an *array*. You need an additional `init(_ tupleArgs: [kv])` method as explained in the referenced thread.

Comment: (And use more descriptive names – starting with an uppercase letter – for types!)

Comment: @MartinR sorry for the trouble and thanks for your help, I suppose I couldn't see the forest for the threes.